# Webkit-transition not working in Chrome on IOS

Tags: ios, css, google-chrome

Im testing a template for use on mobile phones, but can't get it to work in Chrome for IOS. I suspect it to be webkit-transition.

It works fine i Google Chome for PC

[Link to template](http://vindjob.dk/web/)

```
.ac-container article{
background:#fff;
margin-top: -1px;
overflow: hidden;
height: 0px;
position: relative;
z-index: 10;
-webkit-transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.6s linear;
-moz-transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.6s linear;
-o-transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.6s linear;
-ms-transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.6s linear;
transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.6s linear;
```

Comment: In which manner it does not work? An error, please add it. An unexpected result, please describe it.

Comment: The "menu" does not open in Chrome on IOS.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using (~) as in #menuToggle:checked ~ #primary_nav_wrap { position: absolute; left: 0;} to trigger the transition. An upgrade to iOS 9 prevents that from working..... Try using (+) instead of (~)